# How to create an executable file to a GNU-Prolog program?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I have written a prolog program in GNU-Prolog and successfully compiled it , now I want to create an executable file so that the other person only need to click on that file and run the program. I want to know if there is a way to create an executable file from a GNU-Prolog program?

Comment: See the GNU Prolog documentation on `gplc`: http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec15

Comment: I tried to write in Windows cmd but it said `'gplc' is not recognized`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Windows, to compile to an executable you need a C compiler toolchain. Depending, on the version you installed, you need the Microsoft C++ compiler (MSVC) or with gcc (provided by MSYS2/mingw64).

For MSVC, you can install Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community (version 19.28.29335). Once installed, there are 2 .bat file provided with the MS compiler
e.g. vcvars32.bat and vcvars64.bat. Launch the appropriate .bat to obtain a terminal with PATH sets for MSVC.

For gcc, you should install MSYS2 + the gcc toolchain. More information is available here [WINDOWS information](https://github.com/didoudiaz/gprolog/blob/master/src/WINDOWS) (the file details how to compile gprolog  on WINDOWS using either MSYS2/gcc or MSVC).

The gprolog compiler is in the bin sub-directory of the GNU Prolog installation (by default `C:\GNU-Prolog\bin`). You need to add this directory to your PATH.

Go to the directory containing your Prolog file (`cd path_to_your_file`) and compile it with `gplc your_file.pl`.

As mentioned by Paulo, you'll find more information on options you can pass to `gplc` in the [online manual](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec15).